# Adding a column to large dataframe retreived in chunks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have sample code as below:

```
def return_table_df(table_name, chunksize,conn):

        try:                
            df = pandas.read_sql_table(table_name,conn, chunksize=chunksize)            
            return df            
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)

data_frame_chunks = return_table_df('table_name',100000,connection)
```

How do I go about adding a column to the above data-frame which is being retrieved in chunks as it has a few million records in it?

I am hoping there is an alternative to loading the whole data-frame in memory and then adding the column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on what column you want to add, and how you calculate it.

Comment: Can you advise on both scenarios where i need to create a blank column and where the new column depends on other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario 1**
Creating a blank column. This is simple, just assign a new column to the dataframe. You'll need to iterate over the the return value of [`read_sql_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql_table.html), which is an iterator.

```
def return_table_df(table_name, chunksize, conn):
    df_list = []
    for df in pandas.read_sql_table(table_name, conn, chunksize=chunksize) 
        df['blank'] = np.nan 
        df_list.append(df)  

    return pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

---

**Scenario 2**
Add an existing series as a new column. It might be simpler to just add the column at the end.

```
s = ... # your series

def return_table_df(table_name, chunksize,conn):
    df_list = []
    for df in pandas.read_sql_table(table_name, conn, chunksize=chunksize) 
        df_list.append(df)  

    df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)  
    df['newCol'] = s

    return df
```